# swagger securityScheme type property should be written in lower case SPRING BOOT

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi

In the open API V3 in the security scheme, spring doesn't accept the oauth2 in lowercase and that cause a problem in swagger editor

```
SecurityScheme ss = new SecurityScheme();
ss.setDescription(project.getAuthMSRuntimeURL());
ss.type(SecurityScheme.Type.OAUTH2);
```

[Here is the error in swagger editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7psO.png)

Comment: What version of the Swagger Core library do you use?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.setType(...)` instead of `.type(...)`?

Comment: same problem for setType() or .type() and for the swagger core version 2.0.12

Comment: Check out the comments here - https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3076#issuecomment-460196264. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you Yaml.pretty(openApi) fix the issue, it was Json.pretty()